# How to define an interface when the type of a value depends on the key but not all keys are known in advance?

Tags: typescript

Here's an example of a data structure that I want to define as a type in TypeScript:

```
const dataExample = {
    Folder: {
        "Filename.js": {
            lines: {
                total: 100,
                covered: 80,
                pct: 80,
            },
            branches {
                total: 100,
                covered: 80,
                pct: 80,
            },
        },
        Subfolder: {
            "Filename.js": {
                lines: {
                    total: 100,
                    covered: 80,
                    pct: 80,
                },
                branches { 
                    total: 100,
                    covered: 80,
                    pct: 80,
                },
            },
        },
}
```

Typescript seems to require me to describe it this way:

```
interface Datum {
    total: number;
    covered: number;
    pct: number;

}


interface Tree {
    [key: string]: number | Datum | Tree;
}
```

Is there any way of defining it such that TypeScript will understand that the value on keys `lines` and `branch` always has the type `Datum`; that the value on keys `total`, `covered`, and `pct` always has the type `number`; and that the value on any other key always has the type `Tree`? I'm guessing there isn't.

The type definition above is practically worthless. Every time I refer to a key, ex. `dataExample.Folder.Filename1.line`, and try to use it, I get a TypeScript error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '[any type]' can't be used to index type '[Tree | Datum | number]'.  No index signature with a parameter of type '[any type]' was found on type 'Tree'.
```

In order to resolve the error, I have to coerce the type, which defeats the purpose of using a type in the first place.

Edit:

Sherif Elmetainy's solution works perfectly, with one change:

```
    interface Datum {
        total: number;
        covered: number;
        pct: number;
    }
    
    // avoiding using the name File because it's defined in dom
    interface FileEntry {
        lines: Datum;
        branches: Datum;
    }
    
    type TreeEntryExcludeProps = {
        // Add properties lines and branches and make them have type never.
        // This will cause lines and branches to be not allowed in the type
        // The ? is to make them optional because otherwise the compiler will complain about them missing
        [P in keyof FileEntry]?: never;
    };
    
    interface Tree extends TreeEntryExcludeProps { // use an interface and extend it, rather than using a union
        [key: string]: FileEntry | Tree;
    };
    
    //compiler won't complain here
```

In the end I did the following:

```
interface KarmaCoverageDatum {
    total: number;
    covered: number;
    pct: number;
}


interface Datum {
    total: number;
    covered: number;
    skipped: number;
    pct: number;
    
}

interface CoverageDatum {
    excluded: number
    fileCount: number;
    path: string;
    lines: KarmaCoverageDatum;
    branches: KarmaCoverageDatum;
}

interface CoverageTree {
    [key: string]: CoverageDatum | CoverageTree | Datum | number | string;
};

const getTypedDataFromTree = {
    coverageNumbersByKey: (key: 'lines' | 'branches', tree: CoverageTree) => 
        tree[key] as Datum,
    path: (tree: CoverageTree) => tree['path'] as string,
    fileCount: (tree: CoverageTree) => tree['fileCount'] as number,
    excluded: (tree: CoverageTree) => tree['excluded'] as number,
    childTree: (key: string, tree: CoverageTree) => tree[key] as CoverageTree,
};
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html - In this page they use switch statements to control things and encapsulate behaviour in functions, so you hide that from client code. Not sure if that helps you...

Comment: That's definitely helpful and relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added created a possible solution in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzAVwLbIN4BQyxyYA9mHADYBcyIOARtANxEkJkBu0EAJnQbZmUNiWQAHBGEFNWBAL4ECAehXI4XMsD6gA5skwBnfaQAWKEHGwoAYsCopmCOMZTAwAciPI%20EGKD8yKC%20ZNgEoJCwiHYOEACi4FAAnvjsxFSBRnToWNhiJIxQcCAIFtloGDhsSgRgyRIoACpQEAlJyfEAHghUmH4AClBkEj4AvGniasgAgnx8ksONUGDAED6ZIOsaIAtFJWXbJQvYcADWKGAWuGaalw2WEDxQAHTpyNNNZsA%20AO4OVGQLjcyE2R12yH2pXKpDIkMsFA0VCoZF%20QRCV3ujXenwsyAA-MEfORkKcLuYILgRqsyFZAc5XEYUBQLFB-kyKUCwhI4lBkP9kVzsBIqHAQnBGGRMGAKbhsD8TCA9O8ANoDYIgZAXZJkGDIeyORJgFIAXXxgie8lq9UayBabWQE0I4hV2roRmN%20hNdAN7WNqQAPnbWhAasgAGTBtpGlLdXr9CBDEZGNiqFScYW8-m0zwyjMisWa1kQZScEAejR0e0oJ3vGBkKh%20KB0Z3iEgAIgCjisNheACsjO2W%2082yQwRVW6Op7DKLRkAAGAA0I%20nHG4vAEyAAjMvV1OpDJkAAmFejhS7veQ4rQ9bDy9t8izuhL0%20rzjPfh0Hev6cHugn%208lGnc9XyMTBGHrRtoDvS9OziHsIH7QcYPvDIshQ1DH2oZ8L1QrkP03b88OIP9jx-KcQOIq8DnKDCqKwucXyo8R3w3L9cOY0iAOIoDL14s93iUWoywrRgqxDR1JhISCmzosd0PwD51HiKBhj5cdFhGaB6iJUkFVMBjF3wjcdgWA9lGAwTFFLWkKwQcSHVrcQZOgxTpihQ4fAkJZtNSH49KMRVlWnccW2QcjiAYnCIuM1pCI439pH-V9%20OQISgA). I hope it works for you.

```
interface Datum {
    total: number;
    covered: number;
    pct: number;
}

// avoiding using the name File because it's defined in dom
interface FileEntry {
    lines: Datum;
    branches: Datum;
}

type TreeEntryExcludeProps = {
    // Add properties lines and branches and make them have type never.
    // This will cause lines and branches to be not allowed in the type
    // The ? is to make them optional because otherwise the compiler will complain about them missing
    [P in keyof FileEntry]?: never;
}

type Tree = {
    [key: string]: FileEntry | Tree;
} & TreeEntryExcludeProps;

//compiler won't complain here

const a: Tree = {
    folder: {
        "filename.js": {
            lines: {
                total: 0,
                covered: 1,
                pct: 2
            },
            branches: {
                total: 0,
                covered: 1,
                pct: 2
            }
        },
        subfolder: {
            "filename.js": {
                lines: {
                total: 0,
                covered: 1,
                pct: 2
                },
                branches: {
                    total: 0,
                    covered: 1,
                    pct: 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const b: Tree = {
    folder: {
        lines: { // Error lines property is missing total, covered and pct

        }
    }
}

const c: Tree = {
    folder: { // branches property is missing
        lines: { 
            total: 0,
            covered: 1,
            pct: 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I must use and understand less of TypeScript than I thought. This line cause the compiler to complain though: `type Tree = { [key: string]: FileEntry | Tree; & TreeEntryExcludeProps; }`. The error is `Type alias 'Tree' circularly references itself`. How would you resolve the error? If I find a solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: 3.9.2. I found a fix, which I'll share as an edit to my question.

Comment: Defining `Tree` as an `interface` rather than a `type` and extending `TreeEntryExcludeProps` provides exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: Now I'm getting these errors: 

`\`Property 'branches' of type 'undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'FileEntry | FileAndFolderTree'.ts(2411)\``
`\`Property 'lines' of type 'undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'FileEntry | FileAndFolderTree'.ts(2411)\`` Thoughts? It worked in one repo, and then I tried pasting it into another, and the error messages appeared.

Comment: If it works in one repo and doesn't work in another it could be due to different TS versions or different settings in tsconfig.json